# How to maintain django session after updating user email?

Tags: python, django, graphql

I have a django server with graphql and postgres. I have a problem where whenever I update user email the django session is updated and I lose the session on the frontend. How can I maintain the session for that user after an email update?

Comment: Show us the related code and config!

Comment: I am using django authentication but now my question is how can I re-authenticate the user after updating the email. Can you reference any related doc ?